# Javascript / Json Requested Object returns null

Tags: javascript, json

i'm trying to access a local JSON File with JS, turn it into an JS Object by parsing it and logging it to the console. I'm using Live Server in VS Code to set up the Server, therefore the localhost URL.

```
    var requestURL = "http://localhost:5500/sqVol.json";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', requestURL);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();

    var jsonObj = request.response;
    request.onload = function () {
    JSON.parse(jsonObj);
    logData(jsonObj);
    };

    function logData(jsonObj){
      console.log("jsonObj= " + jsonObj);
      //console.log("jsonObj[Datum]= " + jsonObj[Datum]);
      //console.log("jsonObj.Datum= " + jsonObj.Datum);
    }
```

> Output: jsonObj= null

The JSON File:

```
  {
    "Datum": ["03.05.2017","05.06.2017"],
    "Volume": [1338,1445]
  }
```

Here's what I imagine happens:
I'm getting the Answer from *localhost* and parsing it via *JSON.parse* into an JS Object. As soon as the request finished im calling my *logData* function and passing the parsed Data to log it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You're just parsing JSON too many times. remove one JSON.parse and you might get it right because JSON.parse expects a string and you're passing an object.

Comment: `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(request.response);` at this time `response` is `null` or `undefined`. You fail to understand the asynchronous nature of your call.

Comment: Removed it - doesn't change anything unfortunately. edit: and put parse into the onload function. No change either. :(

Comment: `var jsonObj = request.response;` is still null. You fail to understand the asynchronous nature of your call.

Comment: @AaRon you have given `responseType = "json"` already before sending the request so `request.response` is already a javascript object and not a JSON string. So ignore all the code after `request.send()` and just use `console.log(request.response)` inside `onload` function which should be declared **bold** before `request.send()` executes.

Comment: @connexo: you pointed me in the right direction - Thanks! I'll try to handle the request first, make sure the data is received and process it afterwards. Like so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: @Mani Kumar Reddy Kancharla: Thanks! It solved it - ill paste the working Code as answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @connexo pointed out I didn't understand the asynchronous nature of the call. And frankly i still don't but i guess a good starting points will be:

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

[MDN Synchronous and Asynchronous Requests](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

As @Mani Kumar Reddy Kancharla pointed out my response is already a JS Object since i declared `request.responseType = 'json';`

This is how it looks right now:

```
var requestURL = "http://localhost:5500/sqVol.json";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function () {
console.log(request.response);
var jsonObj = request.response;
logData(jsonObj);
};

function logData(jsonObj){
  console.log("jsonObj= " + jsonObj);
  console.log("jsonObj[Datum]= " + jsonObj.Datum);
```

> Ouput: {…} ​ 
>   Datum: Array [ "03.05.2017", "05.06.2017" ] ​ 
>   Volume: Array [ 1338, 1445 ] ​
>
> jsonObj= [object Object]
>   jsonObj[Datum]= 03.05.2017,05.06.2017

As you can see i can also access the *.Datum* Property. I Consider it solved. Thank you!

edit: Added the link provided by connexo.

Comment: Hey @AaRon checkout my answer, it also solves the jsonObj issue by declaring it before onload function rather than inside onload function to solve the scope issue so that it can be used inside logData function

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in your code:

1. You're using `JSON.parse()` too many times on same date which is already converted from JSON string to a JavaScript object and tries to parse a Javascript object raising a Syntax error. You've already mention `request.responseType = 'json'` i.e. [responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) specifies you're receiving a JSON string as response so JavaScript Engine will already parse it and provide you a JavaScript object as `request.response` and you need not parse it. So you could use `JSON.parse(request.responseText)` if you want to parse it yourselves or directly use `request.response` as a JavaScript object.
2. You're trying to store `request.response` into a variable outside the load function which will just provide the value of `request.response` at that time which could be `null` if the response is not received yet. You need to get the response in the `onload` fucntion implementation as it is executed once you receive the response.

So what you're looking for overall is this ->

```
var requestURL = "http://localhost:5500/sqVol.json";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var jsonObj;

function logData(jsonObj){
  console.log("jsonObj= " + JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
  console.log("jsonObj[Datum]= " + JSON.stringify(jsonObj["Datum"]));
  console.log("jsonObj.Datum= " + JSON.stringify(jsonObj.Datum));
  // or simply
  console.log(jsonObj);
  console.log(jsonObj['Datum']);
  console.log(jsonObj.Datum);
}

request.onload = function () {
  jsonObj = request.response;
  logData(jsonObj);
};

request.responseType = 'json';

// finally send the request
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.send();
```

Here `JSON.stringify()` converts a JavaScript Object back to a JSON string.

[Refer to this link to get more information on how to use XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

**EDIT**: Referring to another answer posted, people simply use libraries like [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make asynchronous requests to get data from the web, especially in XML or JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

I used the browser XMLHttpRequest object for Ajax about 12 years ago.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/